# How does this script work to convert the hex to ascii?

Tags: linux, bash

I have got a script which can convert the hex to ASCII, but I donnot know how does it work. Also, I am not sure if it is correct.

I wanna know how does it work. 
The usage is ./hexToASCII ｛hex String｝> {file}

```
hex="$1"

# Convert Hexa decimal to ASCII
for i in $(awk -v len=$(expr "$hex" : '.*') 'BEGIN {for(i=1;i<len;i=i+2) print i;}')
do
  awk -v d=$(printf "ibase=16\n%s\n" $(echo $hex|cut -c$i-$(expr $i + 1)) | bc) 'BEGIN {printf("%c",d);}'
done
```

Comment: As this script is cool, this can be just `xxd -r -p <<<hex_string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if we give ./hexToASCII 505152
then in line 1:
`hex="$1"` will be `hex="505152"`

From the next line:

```
for i in $(awk -v len=$(expr "$hex" : '.*') 'BEGIN {for(i=1;i<len;i=i+2) print i;}')
```

if we take expression by expression then :

```
$(expr "$hex" : '.*')
```

will give the length of the expression. `awk -v len` will assign the length to the variable `len`.

Int the following line:

```
for(i=1;i<len;i=i+2) print i;
```

it will print the values 1,3,5 which will be taken by the main loop `for i in $(...)` and will start executing the loop for values of i (i.e 1,3,5)

Consider the next line:

```
awk -v d=$(printf "ibase=16\n%s\n" $(echo $hex|cut -c$i-$(expr $i + 1)) | bc) 'BEGIN {printf("%c",d);}'
```

In this line,

```
echo $hex|cut -c$i-$(expr $i + 1)
```

During the first execution of the loop, value of i will be 1 and as a result the expression will become `echo $505152|cut -c1-2` and outputs 50(cut column1 and column2). It will be printed in

```
printf("%c",50)
```

to the ascii P.

This will continue for other values of i, resulting in cutting the expression 505152 to 50,51,52 and printing the corresponding ASCII.

In short this script, finds the length of the hex, cut (seperate) it by a multiple of 2 and prints ascii of each piece.

Comment: Just notice that, thanks a million, I am looking at it now.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

(Not the real answer to the question. Just to show the solution is way too complicated. And it would take quite a lot to explain everything in it.)

Much easier solution:

```
[STEP 101] # hex=68656C6C6F0A
[STEP 102] # echo $hex | sed 's/../\\x&/g'
\x68\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F\x0A
[STEP 103] # printf $(echo $hex | sed 's/../\\x&/g')
hello
[STEP 104] #
[STEP 105] # echo $hex | xxd -p -r
hello
[STEP 106] #
```

Or pure Bash:

```
[STEP 107] # for ((i=0; i<${#hex}; i+=2)); do printf "\x${hex:i:2}"; done
hello
[STEP 108] #
```

Comment: i have seen this answer after i finished writing mine, quite the same, deleted

Comment: Thanks a lot, the script is using in a project, so I will try to replace it using the code you give me. The script is using for the data transfer between fpga and PC. Now the script I put here have a confusing out put, let's see what will happened if I change that. Thanks again for your help.